# how to get dynamically created method's name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a method which return its own name. The method looks like this:

```
import inspect
class example(object):
    def getvalue(self):
        return inspect.stack()[0][3]   #returns current method's name
```

Now I am creating a method dyamically in that example class like this.

```
import inspect
class example(object):
    def getvalue(self):
        return inspect.stack()[0][3]   #returns current method's name

if __name__=="__main__":
    e = example()
    e.method=e.getvalue
    print e.method()
```

This gives the output getvalue.
Now I want my getvalue() method to return dynamic method I created's name i.e method. Is there a way to do it in python? If so what changes do I have to do in my getvalue() method so that it returns dynamically created method's name.

```
import inspect
class example(object):
    def getvalue(self):
        return inspect.stack()[0][3]   #what to write here...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.

In Python the very same object can have multiple "names" and thus it doesn't make sense to talk about "the" name of an object.

Methods are objects and the compiler for functions and methods stores the "name" found when the compiling was done in a `__name__` field. If you later move the object around and place it in places reachable using other names the `__name__` field it has won't change.